# Find the maximum x,y value fromn a series of images

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a stack of bitmap images (between 2000-4000 ) that I'm doing a z-projection maximum intensity projection on. So from the stack, I need to get a 2d array of maximum values for each x,y position.

I have devised a simple script that splits up the files into chunks and uses multiprocessing.pool to calculate the maximum array for that chuck. These arrays are then compared to find the maximum for the stack.

It works, but it is slow. My system monitor show that my CPUs are hardly working.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how I might speed things up a bit?

```
import Image
import os
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import sys

#Get the stack of images
files = []
for fn in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
    if fn.endswith('.bmp'):
        files.append(os.path.join(sys.argv[1], fn))

def processChunk(filelist):
    first = True
    max_ = None
    for img in filelist:
        im = Image.open(img)
        array = np.array(im)
        if first:
            max_ = array
            first = False
        max_ = np.maximum(array, max_)
    return max_



if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)

    #Chop list into chunks
    file_chunks = []
    chunk_size = 100
    ranges = range(0, len(files), chunk_size)

    for chunk_idx in ranges:
        file_chunks.append(files[chunk_idx:chunk_idx+chunk_size])

    #find the maximum x,y vals in chunks of 100
    first = True
    maxi = None
    max_arrays = pool.map(processChunk, file_chunks )

    #Find the maximums from the maximums returned from each process
    for array in max_arrays:
        if first:
            maxi = array
            first = False
        maxi = np.maximum(array, maxi)
    img = Image.fromarray(maxi)
    img.save("max_intensity.tif")
```

Comment: You may be hitting a wall in regards to memory accesses- that's why your CPU isn't maxing out. If I'm reading the code correctly, you're fetching an image every time you're picking an x and y.

Instead, create a temporary matrix that's as big as your images, and populate every cell in the matrix. Then, load the next image and do your z-projection. If you're doing multi-core processing, you have to do a final evaluation of which (x,y) cell is the most intense.

Comment: This is a 100% parallel operation, so if you really wanna go crazy here, you could try pycuda or pyopencl. For fairly large images, this would give good performance. For small images the overhead would probably kill the performance gain.

Comment: Just a thought: Your bottleneck may be disk IO if the images are uncompressed.  This doesn't appear to be (other than uncompressing image formats) a CPU-intensive operation.  That would explain the low CPU utilization, at any rate.

Comment: @JoeKington I will try compressed images. Good idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

Did some small benchmarking with sample data and you're right.  Also, turns out (reading your code more closely), most of my original post is wrong.  You are essentially doing the same number of iterations (slightly more, but not 3x more).  I also found out that

```
x = np.maximum(x, y)
```

is slightly faster than both

```
x[y > x] = y[y > x]
#or
ind = y > x
x[ind] = y[ind]
```

I would then alter your code only slightly. Something like:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process(chunk):
    max_ = np.zeros((4000, 4000))
    for im in chunk:
        im_array = np.array(Image.open(im))
        max_ = np.maximum(max_, im_array)
    return max_

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(8)

    chunksize = 500 #4000/8 = 500, might have less overhead
    chunks = [files[i:i+chunksize]
              for i in range(0, len(files), chunksize)]

    # this returns an array of (len(files)/chunksize, 4000, 4000)
    max_arrays = np.array(p.map(process, chunks))
    maxi = np.amax(max_array, axis=0) #finds maximum along first axis
    img = Image.fromarray(maxi) #should be of shape (4000, 4000)
```

I think this is one of the fastest ways you can do this, although I have an idea for a tree or tournament style algorithm, possible a recursive one too.  Good job.

---

How big are the images? Small enough to load two images into memory at once? If so, then can you do something like:

```
maxi = np.zeros(image_shape) # something like (1024, 1024)

for im in files:
    im_array = np.array(Image.open(im))
    inds = im_array > maxi # find where image intensity > max intensity
    maxi[inds] = im_array[inds] # update the maximum value at each pixel 

max_im = Image.fromarray(maxi)
max_im.save("max_intensity.tif")
```

After all iterations, the `maxi` array will contain the maximum intensity for each (x, y) coordinate.  No need to break it into chunks. Also, there's only one `for` loop, not 3, so it will be faster and may not need multiprocessing.

Comment: Should it be ```inds = im_array > maxi ``` and ```maxi[inds] = im_array[inds]``` ?

Comment: It should. Thanks. I edited the post to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks. That's really simple. however my original script is still faster. Your solution took 4m19 my original took 1m20. The images are 4000 x 4000

Comment: I edited my post, but TLDR: your way is pretty good and 1m20s doesn't sound too bad; that's a lot of data.

Comment: @user521469 1m20s is pretty fast for 2000 4000x4000 images. I just benchmarked how long it takes just to open and load those images. Takes 4m10s without any further processing, although I have a fast SSD :).

Comment: @halex Actually the files are 2000*2000. Ones I was processing previously were 4k*4k. I also have SSD. Cheers

Comment: @user521469 Ok that changes the situation and opening and loading "only" takes 40s for 2000 2000x2000 images. Your solution is still pretty fast :).

Comment: @Bill I'm getting 22s now with your additions for 1329 images 2000*2000. I think the speed varies as I have a HD with dual SSD/normal disk. When running the same dataset again it seems to speed up. I assume the files that are used put into the SSD part. I'll try on some more datasets tomorrow. Thanks